# Developing a sticker app for iPhone where do i store the images

Tags: ios, iphone

I was hoping someone could help me understand this.  I'm having an iPhone app sticker developed at the moment.  This app is going to have different categories (angry, happy etc.  There will be some free images but also some in app purchase for other cool ones.

I wanted to know what are the different ways of doing this.  For example, I plan to have more than 25 different sets of stickers for purchase.  I'm not too sure how it all works! Do I host all those pages at the Appstore or do I use a dedicated image hosting provider like Amazon or ...Sorry for the question is my first app and I'm not sure how it all works!

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide your own server for any online content.

Optionally you can include the content inside the app, and only allow access via IAP.

There's no provision for the content being hosted by Apple.

Comment: Thank you Russell for your answer.  what is provision for content?

Comment: I mean that Apple does not provide any method for hosting that content. However, you can use a link to any online hosting service that you like within your app.